# Integral estimate for the solution of the heat equation

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, parabolic-pde

Let $u$ be a solution of $\partial_t u - \Delta u =f$ with initial data $u(0,x) = 0$ on $\mathbb R^N$. How do one prove the following inequality?

> $$
> \int_0^T \int_{\mathbb R^N} \phi(f)(- \Delta) u(s,x)dxds \ge 0,
> $$
>   where $\phi$ is a smooth non-decreasing function.

How can we estimate $$\int_0^T \int_{\mathbb R^N} \phi(f) (-\Delta )u(s,x)dxds$$
from below more precisely?

Comment: Why this should be true?

Comment: When $\phi(t)=t$ the converse inequality is true.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune I don't know why it should be true, but I wish it to be the case. There was a typo and I meant $-\Delta$ in the integral.

Comment: Thank you, I see now.

Comment: Do you know what happens for the elliptic counterpart, that is for $u-\Delta u=f$? Or for specific $\phi?$. Thank you

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune I don't know. As for specific $\phi$, I'm mostly interested in power-type i.e. $\phi(s) = |s|^{m-1}s$.

Comment: I have some ideas how to tackle the problem, but I should work out the details, first. If you like, we could keep in contact via mail and then post the solution, if works. I do not know how to write to you, my  address is giorgio.metafune@unisalento.it.

Comment: @Zyl what happened when you substituted the inhomogeneous heat equation (you get phi(f(x)) (T* f(x)-u(x,T))? You can also use the exactt solution i.e. heat kernel mollified by f.

Comment: Zyl, the "stationary version" of this estimate is called "Stroock-Varopoulos inequality". @Giorgio Metafune, keep me in the loop: I'm currently considering a problem where (a more general version of) this kind of result would be very helpful.

Comment: @Nico It seems that the discussion never started. Where can I find the inequality you mentioned? Thanks

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune, it's Theorem 1 in this paper:  https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-1993-1160303-9.

Comment: @Nico Thanks, but that inequality seems to be weaker. For the $\Delta$ it gives $$\int_{R^N} (-\Delta u) u|u|^{p-2} \ge 0,$$ which is true by integration by parts. For $I-\Delta $ I am wondering about $$\int_{R^N} (-\Delta u)f|f|^{p-2}$$ with $f=u-\Delta u$ which is closer to the parabolic question.

Comment: Solution of the Cauchy problem for the heat equation is not unique. And why for arbitrary $f$ the integral converges?